# Deconvolver for OSX

Tags: convolution, osx

Hi folks,

do you know any deconvolver for osx other than Apple's IR utility?

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few from Varun's cool blog comparing a few deconvolving processes with various applications. Hope this helps!
http://re-sounding.com/2011/06/15/ir-plugin-comparisions/

Comment: Thanks Andy. I've already seen this post before, but what i'm searching for is something like Voxengo, but for OSX. Anyway, i've found out how to extract aif files from Space Designer presets. It's tricky, but it works.